# Transfer of angular momentum during oblique impact with(out) adhesion

Tags: angular-momentum, collision, torque, adhesion

I am solving a problem of 2 identical spherical particles colliding. 
The impact is oblique.
I consider both normal and tangential contact forces.
Tangential force is a combination of elastic force and friction.

I seems reasonable to me that after collision angular momentum should be the same for both particles, i.e. they start spinning in the same direction (particle B acting on particle A creates positive torque, particle A acting on particle B creates opposite force, but the sign of torque is the same). 
This also agrees with some experimental and theoretical results.

The problem starts when adhesion force is added.
What happens with the momentum transfer once particles stick together and therefore cannot spin relative to each other?

It seems to me that they must start spinning as a whole. However I cannot physically reason it quite well.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
thanks for your replies. This is indeed a complex problem. To clarify some details: I am trying to follow a paper by Thornton & Yin, Powder Technology, 65 (1991), "Impact of elastic spheres with and without adhesion".  I am timestep integrating all of the forces involved, i.e. collision is not instantaneous (~100-300 timesteps). When the particles stick due to adhesion there is the effect called "peeling", and this occurs until critical value of tangential force is reached. Then sliding starts (either a rigid body sliding, i.e. pure friction or micro-slip, which is a combination of elastic force and friction, as by Mindlin and Deresiewicz (1953), ASME J. Appl. Mech,20, p327).

I have my simulation match the results of Thornton and Yin except the case of adhesion. The rebound angles (of particles' centres) match, so the model must be almost working, but the contact patch reflection angle does not (this one depends on spin of the particles caused by collision). This makes me think I am not implementing the transfer of angular momentum right in the case of sticking particles.

I will try to work out how to modify the angular momentum of the adhered pair from you replies and the paper you attached.

Comment: When you start adding friction, sticktion and adhesion it becomes a real complex problem because you have to do a mini simulation during each impact to figure out when friction can and cannot be overcome during the impact. See http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/papers/94/ibds94.pdf

Comment: agree with @ja72, since friction (and adhesion) loses energy in heat form, as such the resulting ang. momentum (a component of total energy) will be different

Comment: See https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/courses/amath533/Stewart00.pdf

Comment: Found http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/16741-s07/www/oldlecture16.pdf

Comment: And http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/471/2177/20140859

Comment: See this accepted [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/227812/392) for how to handle friction in contacts. For spheres, things simplify quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  The total angular momentum remains constant.  As the objects are not approaching head-on, there must be angular momentum.  That momentum remains in the joined object as it spins around its COM.

The speed of the spin for the joined object will be proportional to the perpendicular distance and speed of approach, and inversely proportional to the square of the radius.

You can calculate the inbound angular momentum of each sphere about COM
$$ L = \frac12 m v d$$ and the total will be double that.  Similarly, you can gather the moment of inertia for the joined spheres.  Then if you want the speed, you can solve for rotation.  $$ \omega = \frac{L}{I}$$

Any friction can't remove angular momentum from the system.  It just removes energy (which could also be calculated given information on the spheres).

Comment: the question says it has friction (as well as adhesion), as such energy is lost in heat, which makes the angular momentum (a component of total energy) to be different

Comment: I was only talking about the adhesion case which seemed to be the question.  Friction is irrelevant if they stick.

Comment: regarding your edit, energy is changed due to friction, energy also is calculated using ang. momentum, as such ang. momentum will be different, you are wrong (except if friction is considered negligible in which case you are only slightly wrong effectively correct)

Comment: The energy of the combined object will be less (due to friction or deformation or similar), but the total momentum must be conserved, yes?

Comment: no i dont think so, momentum is conserved when there are no dissipative forces (as friction)

Comment: consider 2 objects moving with high speed which collide plastically and stop moving (where did the momentum go? it turned into heat) the (combined) object is now at higher temperature

Comment: @bowlofred - You are correct. While collisions can change the total mechanical energy of a set of colliding objects, they do not change total linear momentum or total angular momentum. They just transfer it amongst objects involved in the collision. You have to beware, though, that there are two aspects of angular momentum: The $I\omega$ terms that represent objects rotating about their centers of mass, and the $m \vec r \times \vec v$ terms that represent the angular momentum due to translation. You do not have this latter set of terms in your answer.

Comment: @DavidHammen and bowlofred, newtonian mechanics (without dissipative forces as friction and adhesion et al), implies the conservation of momentum/angular momentum in collisions, maybe i did not understand the question myself

Comment: @NikosM. - Linear and angular momentum are conserved in collisions even with dissipative forces.

Comment: @DavidHammen, i have the impression this is not so, can you help here?

Comment: @NikosM. - It's a consequence of Newton's third law. Looking at the objects involved in a collision as a system, those collision forces are internal to that system. Internal forces don't change the total linear or angular momentum. Only external forces and torques do. Integrating those external forces and torques over the very short time span over which a collision occurs will result in a negligibly small change in the total linear and angular momentum of the objects participating in the collision. These small changes, if any, can safely be ignored in most collision events.

Comment: @DavidHammen, ok we agree there as an idealisation of a collision process

Comment: @DavidHammen, Actually, I was assuming the spheres were not rotating, and the only angular momentum was due to translation.  You're correct that any angular momentum of rotation adds to the total.

Comment: @NikosM. - It's more than that. You apparently are thinking that the collision forces themselves can change the total linear and angular momentum of the colliding objects. They can't, and the only idealization here is Newton's third law.

Comment: @DavidHammen, no (and i would not like to turn this into a chat), we were talking about dissipative forces. On a side-note realistic collisions are not elastic and do involve various kinds of dissipation, as such we agree on the idealisation which **can be** a very good approximation

Comment: @NikosM, friction only affects momentum when it is external to your system.   As an example, you usually don't consider the momentum of the room you are in (or the earth), so a box sliding on the floor "loses" momentum as friction works on the box.  But when friction is internal to the system, it cannot remove momentum.  In this question where only the two spheres are considered, translational and rotational momentum are conserved, even when friction is considered.  It does remove KE, though.

Comment: @NikosM. - This conversation will probably disappear if you don't want to continue this in chat. Yes, we were talking about dissipative forces, but between the colliding objects. Unless those forces violate Newton's third law, they cannot change the total linear momentum or total angular momentum of the colliding objects.

Comment: @DavidHammen, no dont have time right now for this, thanx though. But isnt friction a non-conservative force in any manifestation (meaning if motion direction is reversed the effects are not reversed etc..)

Comment: @NikosM.- Non-conservative means mechanical energy isn't conserved. Conservation of mechanical energy is a consequence of time reversibility of the underlying interactions. Time reversibility (or lack thereof) does not come into play in conservation of linear and angular momenta. Those result from spacial symmetries. Looking from the perspective of Newton's laws as opposed to Noether's theorems, conservation of linear and angular momenta are a direct consequence of Newton's third law. You can find a derivation in almost every upper undergraduate classical mechanics text.