# How do I handle elastic contacts in a simulation with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, collision, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm trying to simulate a wheel as it hits the ground.

**Problem 1**

Suppose a disc is dropped from a height. It has initial velocity of $-x,-y$ caused by throwing and gravity. It has no initial angular velocity. When it hits the ground it should have some rotation resulting from the collision.

- How to calculate force that caused torque for that rotation?

**Problem 2**

The same disc is dropped from height. It doesn't have velocity on the side direction. It already spinning fast. When it hits the ground the spinning should cause some translation.

- How to calculate force that caused this linear acceleration?
- Some rotation must be lost in the collision, how to calculate that?

To simplify assume static $friction = 1$ and $g = -10$.

Comment: Please read [this Meta post on how to ask homework(-like) questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: I think he is asking about how to handle elastic collisions _with friction_. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Remove the code listing. It confuses things. To ask about code post to [SO]. You are asking about a physics concept, right? Stick to asking with equations and only mention that this goes into a simulation in passing.

Comment: If you re-word the question such as "How do I handle elastic contacts in a simulation when friction is present.." and explain "For example, a disk a dropped .." then you can petition to re-open the question (if you want to). Maybe other responses would be of value to you.

Comment: Actually I'm simulating vehicle wheels. My logic is the drive wheels receive torque from the engine and accumulate energy in its rotation. So that when the vehicle did a jump and spin its wheels then land on the ground the spinning wheels propel the vehicle a bit with its stored energy. Your equations have been successful with a single wheel without vehicle. But I'm having trouble on applying this with the added mass of the vehicle. Can you point me to existing answers or sources that can help me with this problem?

Comment: My first equation shows the effective mass matrix at the contact point. When you start adding additional connected bodies this shows up in a updated mass matrix. It gets really complicated really fast. Look up `Recursive Newton Euler Dynamics`. For the basics of dynamic modeling look into (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd1.pdf) and (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider a rough surface (infinite friction). At the moment of impact there is a momentum transfer from the ground to the disk. This is called impulse and it is a vector passing through the contact point. With a rough surface the impulse in the horizontal direction (along the contact) is independent of the impulse in the vertical direction (contact normal).

The effect of the two impulses $J_x$ and $J_y$ have on the motion of the disk can be analyzed using the 2D inertia matrix at the contact point *A*.

$$\begin{pmatrix}J_x \\J_y \\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} m & 0 & -m R \\ 0 & m & 0 \\ -m R & 0 & I+m R^2 \end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \Delta \dot{x}_A \\ \Delta \dot{y}_A \\ \Delta \omega \end{pmatrix} $$

<sub>NOTE: This is a direct consequence of the equations of motion at the center of mass, expressed in terms of the linear motion (change) at *A* $(\Delta \dot{x}_A,  \Delta \dot{y}_A)$ and the angular velocity (change) $\Delta \omega$.</sub>

From the above we get the impulse required for a specific change in linear velocity (as well as the change in angular velocity).

$$ \begin{align} J_x & = \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{R^2}{I} \right)^{-1} \Delta \dot{x}_A
\\ J_y & = \left( m \right) \Delta \dot{y}_A \\
\Delta \omega &= \frac{R}{I} J_x \end{align} $$

The elastic collision law states that the change in motion is such that the final velocity *at the contact* is a fraction $\epsilon$ of the initial velocity, but in the opposite direction. For the impact with an immovable floor this is

$$ \begin{pmatrix}  \dot{x}_A \\ \dot{y}_A \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} \Delta \dot{x}_A \\ \Delta \dot{y}_A  \end{pmatrix} = -\epsilon \begin{pmatrix}  \dot{x}_A \\ \dot{y}_A  \end{pmatrix} $$

So the change in linear velocity is given by

$$  \begin{pmatrix} \Delta \dot{x}_A \\ \Delta \dot{y}_A  \end{pmatrix} = -(1+\epsilon) \begin{pmatrix}  \dot{x}_A \\ \dot{y}_A  \end{pmatrix} $$

and the change in angular velocity

$$\begin{align} 
  \Delta \omega &= \frac{R}{I} \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{R^2}{I} \right) \Delta \dot{x}_A \\ 
  & = -(1+\epsilon) \frac{R}{I} \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{R^2}{I} \right) \dot{x}_A\\ 
  & = -(1+\epsilon) \frac{R}{I} \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{R^2}{I} \right) \left(\dot{x}+R \omega \right) \end{align}  $$

where $\dot{x}$ and $\omega$ are the initial horizontal and rotation velocity of the center of mass.

The final velocities at the center are found by transforming the (change) motion from the contact point to the center of mass

$$\begin{align} 
  \dot{x}^\star &= \dot{x} + (\Delta \dot{x}_A-R \Delta \omega) \\
  \dot{y}^\star &= \dot{y} + (\Delta \dot{y}_A) \\
  \omega^\star & = \omega + \Delta \omega
\end{align}$$

After some simplifications I get

$$\begin{align} 
  \dot{x}^\star &= - \frac{(1+\epsilon)I R \omega + (\epsilon I-m R^2) \dot{x}}{I+m R^2}\\
  \dot{y}^\star &= -\epsilon \dot{y}\\
  \omega^\star & = \omega - \frac{(1+\epsilon)m R (\dot{x}+R \omega)}{I+m R^2}
\end{align}$$

Impulses are back calculated as $$\begin{align} J_x &= -(1+\epsilon) \left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{R^2}{I} \right)^{-1} (\dot{x}+R \omega) \\ J_y &=-(1+\epsilon) m \dot{y} \end{align}$$

<sub>NOTE: $\left( \frac{1}{m} + \frac{R^2}{I} \right)^{-1}$ is the effective mass in the horizontal direction at the contact point.</sub>

---

Finally, to handle finite friction you must limit $|J_x| \leq \mu | J_y |$ but retaining the direction (sign) it would have with infinite friction. Since $J_x$ is specified the change in horizontal and rotational motion is going to be different also accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm trying to understand this, it might take a while :)

Comment: Draw a diagram with the disk in contact, the impulse components and do `(net impulse) = (mass) ( change in linear speed of center)` and `(net impulse moment about center) = (mass moment of inertia) (change in angular speed)`